# How to print the field product_code in purchase reports?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

i'm trying to customized **report_purchasequotation.xml** and **report_purchaseorder.xml**. I have added a new **th** to add Product reference at the supplier in my reports. My problem is when i use **span t-field="order_line.product_id.product_code"** (field product_code in the model  product.supplierinfo ) it shows error **QWebException: 'product_code'**. Any help please ?

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th><strong>Article</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Référence fournisseur</strong></th>
                    <th><strong>Désignation</strong></th>
                    <th class="text-center"><strong>Expected Date</strong></th>
                    <th class="text-right"><strong>Qty</strong></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr t-foreach="o.order_line" t-as="order_line">
                    <td>
                        <span t-field="order_line.name"/>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <span t-field="order_line.product_id.product_code"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>

                    <td class="text-center">
                        <span t-field="order_line.date_planned"/>
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        <span t-field="order_line.product_qty"/>
                        <span t-field="order_line.product_uom" groups="product.group_uom"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is a `one2many` field on the `product.template` that is called `seller_ids`. This is the relation between `product_supplierinfo` and `product_template`. So you can do something like this to get all the supplier codes:

```
<span><t t-esc="', '.join([x.product_code for x in order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids])" /></span>
```

You can show all the product codes in a table as well

```
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Supplier</th>
            <th>Product Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr t-foreach="order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.seller_ids" t-as="s">
            <td>
                <span t-esc="s.name.name"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span t-esc="s.product_code"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I have correct the answer, check if it works with the `t` tag. If not write the error you are getting

Comment: For printing products variant i use **<span t-esc="', '.join([x.attribute_id for x in o.order_line.product_id.product_tmpl_id.attribute_line_ids])"/>** but it shows error could you help me ?

Comment: You need to write a different question for that

Comment: could you help me with this problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642932/how-to-print-the-product-variants-in-report-sale-order